# How can I deserialize this json code to c# object?

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, json.net, json-deserialization

I have an example json code from facebook graph

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":"00000000000",
         "name":"Music1"
      },
      {  
         "id":"00000000001",
         "name":"Music2"
      },
      {  
         "id":"00000000002",
         "name":"Music3"
      }
   ],
   "paging":{  
      "cursors":{  
         "before":"ODYxODU3ODI4NDgZD",
         "after":"MTkwMDA4MDc0MzcyMjM1"
      },
      "next":"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/USER_ID/music?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&pretty=0&fields=id%2Cname&limit=25&after=MTkwMDA4MDc0MzcyMjM1"
   }
}
```

I found an online json2csharp code generator and generate this:

```
public class Datum
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Cursors
{
    public string before { get; set; }
    public string after { get; set; }
}

public class Paging
{
    public Cursors cursors { get; set; }
    public string next { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
    public Paging paging { get; set; }
}
```

I tried deserialize it to this class structure in multiple ways, but i always got difficulties. I can deserialize "paging" and "cursor" correctly, but i haven't found way to deserialize "data: id,name". Can you help me with this one?

Comment: What are you de-serializing with? Json.NET? Something else?

Comment: This de-serializes correctly for me. Show me your code where you de-serialize.

Comment: Yes Json.NET. e.g. RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json), but it don't give me data: name and id

Comment: There's something else going on then. http://imgur.com/a/MlRwv

Comment: post the code in the question

Comment: Yes, please post as much code as you can around how you're getting the json data to begin with up to where you de-serialize.

Comment: Ok i found a solution, @KSib thanks for help with this image, i forgot to initialize data=rootObject.data[], and i was trying to get rootObject.data.name directly; my beginner bad :/

Comment: It's okay. I'm glad you figured out what the problem was.